# Page Number in Word Document

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I am creating a training document that includes facilitator and participant information.  I need to have the facilitator page number the same as the corresponding participant page number.  Basically I need the page numbering format to be 1,1,2,2, etc.  Any ideas

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical task to do but follow my steps closely and you'll be able solve it

1. Open Word
2. Add content to 2-3 pages (or simply use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to add page breaks. (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> if you are on mac))
3. On the menu click on Insert tab and click Footers > edit Footer (Or you can do it by double clicking header/footer).
4. Now switch to Headers & Footers tab in the menu (If you are not taken there).
5. Check `Different Odd and Even Pages`.

Till here its an easy part. Now comes the typical part.

6. Click on Header or Footer (where ever you want to insert the page number) of **ODD page** and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> (On Windows) OR <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> (On Mac) Exactly 3 times. It will insert `{{{}}}` in the place. add exacly like this `{= {= {PAGE} / 2} + 0.5}` **Don't forget to add spaces between the symbols `/`,`+` etc. and Don't modify curly braces**.
7. Now move to **EVEN page** Header or Footer (where ever you want to insert the page number) and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> (On Windows) OR <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> (On Mac) Exactly 2 times. It will insert `{{}}` in the place. add exacly like this `{= {PAGE} / 2}}`. **Don't forget to add spaces between the symbols `/`,`+` etc. and Don't modify curly braces**.

Added screenshot for your ease (I use office 2016 on mac. it might look little bit different on your machine if you use Windows or an older version of Office)

[image: Word Page No.]

Now One last and final step:

8. Press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> and It'll evaluate to page numbers.

Just for your ease I have uploaded a sample document with page format you requested on my One Drive. You can access it here: https://1drv.ms/w/s!Ao_mBlYpT75Slp16fcwEWfprDndSfQ

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

1. On the **Header & Footer Tools** > **Design** tab, in the **Options** group, select both **Different First Page** and **Different Odd & Even Pages**.
2. In the first-page footer (or header – wherever you want the page number to appear), just insert the page number as usual.
3. In the even-page footer/header, insert this field code: `{={PAGE}/2}`.
   (Take the actual page number of every even page, and divide by 2, so that page 2 become numbered as 1, page 4 as 2, and so on.)
4. In the odd-page footer/header, insert this field code: `{=INT({PAGE}/2)+1}`.
   (Take the actual page number of every odd page after page 1, divide by 2, convert the result to an integer, which effectively rounds it down, and then add 1, so that page 3 becomes numbered as 2, page 5 as 3, and so on.)

Of course, this approach assumes that the numbering starts right on the first page of the actual file. If you also have a cover page and other front matter for each guide, you'll need to insert a section break before the content that you want to number in this way. You'll also need to adjust the page number format so that the numbering starts at 1.